# Jquery plugin qTip - scrollLeft is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make use of [qTip JQuery plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#create).

I have tried to implement it but I get an error reported by firebug.

```
f(window).scrollLeft is not a function
[Break on this error] (function(f){f.fn.qtip=function(B,u){var...asses:{tooltip:"qtip-blue"}}}})(jQuery);
```

Please have a look at [my setup](http://174.132.101.73/~dandy/tester/test.html).

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is that a `var asses` I see in there?!

Comment: That doesn't really help me - although its funny!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I viewed source on your page and it looks like the jQuery version your using is older than what qTip requires.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#requirements

```
jQuery version 1.2.6 and above
```

http://174.132.101.73/~dandy/tester/jquery.js

```
jQuery 1.2.3
```

update and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I would have never worked that out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until the DOM is loaded before trying to attach qtip to it, so wrap your code in:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Also check the version requirements as Samuel points out.

Comment: I have the $(document).ready(function() - wrapped around it but removed it as I thought that might be causing the problem!